# What is the error: "There is no line property 'xerror'" when plotting upper and lower error bars?

Tags: plot

I am trying to plot a graph and one of the sets of data points has different upper and lower errors. I have called the error on x "xerror" and the upper and lower errors "xerror_u" and "xerror_l", respectively.

Note that I am using data from a csv file. I have X, Y, Xerror_u, Xerror_l and Yerror.

This is my code:

```
from pylab import * 
import csv

data=csv.reader(open('Documents/exoplanets.csv','rU'))

X=[]  
Y=[]  
Xerr_l=[]  
Xerr_u=[]  
Yerr=[]

for row in data:
    X.append(float(row[3]))
    Y.append(float(row[1]))
    Xerr_l.append(float(row[4]))
    Xerr_u.append(float(row[5]))
    Yerr.append(float(row[2]))

errorbar(X,Y,Xerr=[Xerr_l,Xerr_u],Yerr=Yerr,fmt='r+',ecolor='k')
title("Exoplanet data") 
show()
```

The error I get is: There is no line property in "Xerror".

What is wrong with my code and how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe already solved it yourself, but I'll post it anyway.

Assuming you were using the latest version to the date of your post (from Oct 2014) 1.4.2, according to [the pyplot doc](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=pyplot#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar) the arguments should be lowercase: `xerr` and `yerr`. Not Xerr and Yerr.

I tried it on matplotlib 1.4.3 and capitalization does make a difference.